# init Zend_Cache in Bootstrap (UTF-8)

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-cache

I'm tryng to Cashe controllers from **Bootstrap**

I have controller called **questionController** and I'm using Arabic language
when I cached the questionController (like code below) its work properly . but when I added routing to this controller like **my.local/اسئله** to **questionController** cache dose not work its only work when i call controller directly with his name but with his routing (Arabic) name dose not work.

my function function in my **Bootstrap.php** is

```
protected function _initCache()
{
        mb_internal_encoding("UTF-8");
        $dir = "/var/www/data/cache/";
        $frontendOptions = array(
            'lifetime' => 10800,
            'automatic_serialization' => true,
            'debug_header' => true,                
            'regexps' => array(
                '$' => array('cache' => false),
                '/question' => array('cache' => true),
            ),
            'default_options' => array(
                'cache_with_cookie_variables' => true,
                'make_id_with_cookie_variables' => false
            )
        );

        $backendOptions = array(
                'cache_dir' =>$dir
        );
        $cache = Zend_Cache::factory('Page',
                             'File',
                             $frontendOptions,
                             $backendOptions);
        $cache->start();
 }
```

**and my rout is**

```
$router->addRoute('questionRout', new Zend_Controller_Router_Route('اسئله', array('controller' => 'question', 'action' => 'view')));
```

**my.local/question ---> cache working**

**my.local/اسئله      --->  not working**
and I used mb_internal_encoding("UTF-8").

Please help me 
 Thanks

Answer (score 1):

in your front end options for the cache you are isolating out the /question url slug to be included in the cache

```
'/question' => array('cache' => true),
```

so this will exclude other paths.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
but its work and when i enter  /question its caching well but /que not working .